# How create a Unit Test for _HttpContext.SignOutAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I has implemented in my controller on the action logout the method HttpContext!.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

But I don't know how mock it in my Unit Tests, In my try I receive the error Value cannot be null. (parameter 'provider');

My IAction Logout:

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private radonly IUSerService _userService;
    
    public AuthController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
            await HttpContext!.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
}
```

My Unit Test:

```
public class AuthControllerTest
{
   private readonly AutoMocker _autoMocker;
   private readonly Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> _httpContextAccessor;
   private readonly AuthController _authController;

   public AuthControllerTest(){
      _autoMocker = new();
      _httpContextAccessor = _autoMocker.GetMock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
      _authController = _autoMocker.CreateInstance<AuthController>();
   }

   [Fact]
   public async Task Logout_ReturnSuccess_WhenLogoutWithSuccess
   {  
      var userClaims = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[]{
      new Claim(ClaimType.Name, "testUser"),
      new Claim(ClaimType.Role, "Admin"),
      }));

      _httpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.User).Returns(userClaims);

      var result = await _authController.Logout();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `IHttpContextAccessor` in controller? It already exposes Context property.

Comment: @GuruStron, thats true, I don't need, but about the test, I don't know how I can test this part yeat, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

[`SignOutAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signoutasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-authenticationhttpcontextextensions-signoutasync(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpcontext-system-string)) is an extension method, not an actual method on `HttpContext` itself.

The implementation of it can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/3e07f5d1b367ba1b3bf8f7bedf5aa8093bf0165f/src/aspnetcore/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L183). It ultimately calls [this extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/3e07f5d1b367ba1b3bf8f7bedf5aa8093bf0165f/src/aspnetcore/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L193), which then resolves `IAuthenticationService` and calls [`SignOutAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iauthenticationservice.signoutasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0) on that service.

So to mock this, you'll want to mock `IAuthenticationService` and ensure that your mock gets returned from the service container.

Comment: Can you provide a example to implement it?

Comment: @Joao I'll try to this evening. I'm afraid I had to sleep last night so couldn't write more. I'm not familiar with AutoMock but I sense that `var authService = _autoMocker.GetMock<IAuthenticationService>();` might be enough to create the mock, and then you just need to mock the method. I'll try that and get back to you though.